What effect will a planet’s narcotic atmosphere have on sound of music at rave parties?
I have a tropical (higher average temperature and smaller, more evenly-distributed continents) habitable (for humans) planet. Apart from one thing: it has the following atmosphere: 
I still want humans to use this world as a tourist attraction and one of the attractions is that you do not need to take any alcohol or substances to ‘get high’; you simply need to breathe in the air (thanks to Nitrogen Narcosis).
My question: Given that a higher air pressure along with a different composition will affect sounds, will music in the rave parties on this world need to be tuned entirely differently than what we have on Earth?

"The syndrome may cause exhilaration, giddiness, extreme anxiety, depression, or paranoia" Wikipedia - just to comment on the premise, doesn't seem 100% a good night out.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Sorry I should specify that the Nitrogen partial pressure isn’t at the high end of that narcotic range. It’s at the lower end. Between 4-5 atm.

The easy answer to your question is yes. The dramatic example is inhaling a balloon full of helium. Musical instruments would have the same problem. They'd have to be tuned to the resonance of the ambient atmospheric content of the planet. Your bigger problem is any semblance of administration or control. I suppose your government, police, and DJs are all wearing oxygen masks?

I'm with edp. Nitrogen either liquid or gas is widely available and dirt cheap on Earth (you really only pay for the container and shipping), and I've never heard of anybody using it to get high. And that's saying something, given the horrible things people will imbibe...

@gs Nitrogen at high enough pressures causes a narcotic effect. This is often experienced by scuba divers and is known as ‘rapture of the deep’. Here’s a video of what it’s like: https://youtu.be/flYmFAe6OmU?feature=shared

@JBH unless there's a Time Lord involved - even when they are using different gaseous mixtures to prevent their enemy's being able to use voice recognition successfully, at least the 4th Doctor was unaffected and could speak normally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Robots_of_Death

I think you misunderstand the concept of a narcotic, largely due to the political use of the word. Medically, narcotics are things that depress nervous system function.   This has nothing to do with hallucinogenic or euphoric effects, despite what DARE might tell you. Medically, nicotine is a narcotic and marijuana is not. MDMA is DEFINITELY not a narcotic. Don't be fooled by political miscategorization and use of scary words. When they say "nitrogen narcosis," they mean drowsiness and muscular dysfunction, mostly caused by oxygen deprivation.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Good with the bad :D

This has me wondering if the "helium balloon" affect has more to do with the impedance mismatch between the air in the speaker's vocal tract and the air around the listener's head.  In the normal situation on Earth, sound waves will propagate differently in the helium source and normal destination, and the interface will do things. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_impedance But if singer & listener are in the same environment, the effects might cancel out...

Then again, whether they cancel depends on how much sound generation has to do with wavelength vs frequency. The mapping between them is going to depend on the ambient medium... My suspicion is that in a human vocal tract, our bodies set wavelengths and the relevant part for hearing is frequency.  I suspect woodwinds & brass do much the same thing. Strings probably match in frequency as soon as it gets in the air, and the only wavelengths that matter are in the instrument's material. Percussion might be a mix. Expect synthesizers to be frequency-only...

The helium chipmunk effect is a function of your vocal cords behaving differently. Higher-frequency sound carries higher energy; there is no way for the propagation medium to shift sound to higher frequency.

@gs - Nitrogen is cheap, but an hyperbaric tank where you can be administered gases at high pressure is not cheap.

Snobby Musician Elitist answer
For reference I am not into Dance or Rave music - I am a Drummer and I listen to Metal (the faster and heavier the better).
A good friend of mine once remarked that the only way to enjoy Dance or House or Rave Music was to take MDMA. And to be clear, this is not the first Drug and Music combination (Psychedelic Rock, Stoner Metal etc.)
To which my first answer is:
They will be so high off their tits that they wont care that the music is shite
However...
My slightly less Elitist Musician Answer
Initial recordings may tune different to have the music be perceived as the same...
(you can sense a but coming)
Good Dance musicians (and yes, they do exist - if you put on the Prodigy, I am gonna bop around like it is the mid 90s) will instead seek to leverage the conditions of where they play to enhance the music.
As such, it will be original compositions, written to be played in such an atmosphere.
Just like how crappy dance music written by people high as a kite can only be enjoyed by people high as a kite
(sorry, the snob came out again)
But in all seriousness - the evolution of music has shown when there is a new way to make sound (or perhaps - a new way to hear sound) you will find people experimenting with it and using it to write new types and styles of music - which will mean eventually:
No, They will not be tuned differently to what is on earth, they will be written for the atmosphere they are to be performed in

Good answer. But when someone asks the band to “play Free Bird!”, will the crackle from the guitarist’s taser sound the same as on Earth? :-)

We already have space travel to whatever planets we want for cheap (given that we’re able to use it to go to raves on weekends). My bet is that we also have the tech to preprocess the speakers to make bad music sound at least as bad on Nitroworld as on Earth!

I enjoy music made high as a kite sober though?

@Hobbamok - So do I - but a little bit of snark made a funnier answer.

My stereo came with a device to automatically balance the speakers.
It's essentially microphone with known characteristics and you place it where you're going to listen.  Then you hit the "setup mode" button on the stereo and it plays a series of generated tones.  Since it knows what the tones should sound like it can adjust the signals to the speakers until it sounds right.
On my stereo this is designed to be done once a year or so and not while you're listening to music, but it's not a stretch to imagine an active and continuous process that compares the actual sound to the original signal (recorded music or off the engineers board) and have this happen with any music in real time.
If you throw in some beam forming technology you could have each participant listening to the music of their choice without an overall cacophony. You could even engineer a silent spot in the middle of the dance floor for a private conversation.

All you need is a decent equalizer
The accepted answer doesn't address the question of how the sound of the music will actually change. The answer is "not much." For a simple way to understand why, know that you can buy underwater speakers to play music in a pool. Underwater is a heck of a lot more different a transmission medium as the atmosphere you propose, but music sounds largely the same underwater.
How does the medium affect sound propagation? Two ways. First, the speed of sound may be faster or slower, generally faster for higher density. But that doesn't really affect how the music sounds, except maybe in large amphitheaters where you have to rethink the placement of in-crowd speakers to avoid doubling and echo effects.
The second effect is that different frequencies are scattered or attenuated more strongly than others. This is already true; high frequencies are attenuated more quickly than low frequencies. The further you are from the source, the more the sound is dominated by base tones. If this dispersive attenuation is stronger with your proposed atmospheric mix, your music might sound poorly mixed, with e.g. the bass drowning out the vocals. And to combat this effect, we already use equalizers, which selectively amplify different frequency ranges to "rebalance" the sound to account for the acoustic properties of the amplifiers, speakers, and environment.
So, on this planet your audio engineers may generally tune the equalizers differently than for earth atmosphere, but that should be all that's necessary for the music to sound the same to the audience.

People would overdose after a while, drop and recover- so every 10 minutes, there is a "Robter miles- children" phase, where everyone just falls over and gets it out of there system, before the rave restarts. NarCan is a party drug, because then you can party without constantly "dozzing" off.
